# Is there any way to determine if there exists a continuous extension for a function

Tags: real-analysis

I wanted to see if there was some way to determine if there exists a continuous extension for a function. Specifically, I am looking to know if there is a continuous extension for

$f(x)=1/q $ for all $x=p/q$ where $p/q$ is a fraction in the rational numbers in lowest form. Could I use a fractal or some other iterative process to create this continuous extension?

Comment: Continuous extension to where? $\mathbb{R}$? And, in general there is no general way without special conditions. I'm not sure about your specific example but again it would depend where you're trying to extend to. I doubt it since there is likely no sensible way to define $f(\pi)$ for example.

Comment: your function is not continuous so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example, we run into trouble before extending anything anywhere: your function is not continuous on the rationals. We have
$$
   \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n-1}{n} = 1, \text{ but } \lim_{n \to \infty} f\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n = 0 \ne f(1) = 1.
$$

In general, if a function on the rationals can be continuously extended to the reals, there is only one way to do it. Say we have $f(p/q) = 1/q$ for all rational inputs, and we want to know $f(\sqrt2)$. Then take any sequence of rational numbers you like that converges to $\sqrt2$, such as $1, 1.4, 1.41, 1.414, 1.4142, \dots$. If the extension is continuous, then $f(1), f(1.4), f(1.41), f(1.414), f(1.4142), \dots$ must converge to $f(\sqrt2)$. So take the limit of the sequence $f(1), f(1.4), f(1.41), \dots$ and define that to be the value of $f(\sqrt2)$.

So then we must ask:

- Is this well-defined: do all sequences that converge to $\sqrt2$ give the same value when we do this? In this case, you can probably convince yourself that the answer is **yes**: you'll end up with $f(\sqrt2) = 0$ no matter which sequence you pick. (The same should be checked for every other irrational number.)
- Is the resulting function actually continuous? Here the answer is **no**, for pretty much the same reason that the function wasn't continuous on the rationals to begin with. (I'm not sure, but I believe that if we start with any function that's continuous on the rationals, and the limit procedure above is well-defined, then we'll get a function that's continous on the reals.)